# find the $x$ : $x^2(x-1)^2+x^2=8(x-1)^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> find the $x$ :
>
> $$x^2(x-1)^2+x^2=8(x-1)^2$$

---

My Try :

$$x^2(x-1)^2+x^2=8(x-1)^2\\ x^2(x^2-2x+1)+x^2=8(x^2-2x+1)\\x^4-2x^3+x^2+x^2=8x^2-16x+8\\x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8=0$$

Now What ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Try the divisors of $8$.

Comment: Why ?Nothing changes

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $x=2$ is a solution. So
$$x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8 =(x-2)(x^3-6x+4)$$
$x=2$ is also a solution of $x^3-6x+4=0$. So
$$x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8 =(x-2)^2(x^2+2x-2)=0$$
The roots are $x=2,1\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: how did you find out that :$$x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8 =(x-2)(x^3-6x+4)$$

Comment: By inspection: we know we have some cubic factor $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d$, but we know $a=1$ to get $x^4$, $d=4$ to get the constant term $-8$, and then I just noticed that $b=0$ and $c=-6$ works. You could also do it by polynomial long division (i.e. the Euclidean algorithm for polynomials)

Comment: @Almot1960 It is called the rational root test.

Comment: @Almot1960 To get your identity you just divide your degree-4 polynomial $p(x)$ by $x-2$, since you already know that $p(2)=0$ (this is called the factor theorem). Then the degree-3 polynomial is the quotient of the division.

Answer (score 0):

So it can be checked that your polynomial $$x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8=0$$ has a factor of $(x-2)$. We check that this is so by the [factor theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factor_theorem). Then (and it should be checked by you too) that by carrying out the appropriate algebraic division that

$$x^4-2x^3-6x^2+16x-8=(x-2)(x^3-6x+4).$$

Then by a similar argument, we may divide this through by $(x-2)$ again to give

$$(x^3-6x+4)=(x-2)(x^2+2x-2).$$

Then apply the quadratic formula to yield

$$x^2+2x-2=0 \Rightarrow -1\pm\sqrt{3},$$

so altogether $$x=2, -1\pm\sqrt{3}.$$